# How do I explicitly find a basis that transforms a matrix into a Sylvester form?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, change-of-basis

> Let $\beta$ be a symmetric bilinear form represented by the
> transformation matrix with regards to the standard basis:
> \begin{align*}  A:= \begin{pmatrix}   2 & 0 & 2\\   0 & 6 & 0\\   2 &
>  0 & 5  \end{pmatrix} \in \operatorname{Mat}(3, \mathbb{R}).
> \end{align*} Find a basis  $B = \{b_1, b_2, b_3\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$
> such that $D = (\beta(b_i, b_j))$ of $\beta$ with regards to $B$ is
> given through: \begin{align*}  D = \begin{pmatrix}  \epsilon_1 & 0 & 0
>  \\  0 & \epsilon_2 & 0 \\  0 & 0 & \epsilon_3  \end{pmatrix},
> \end{align*} where $\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2, \epsilon_3 \in \{-1, 0,
>  1\}$.

I started with the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A$ and found the orthonormal basis.$$a_1=\begin{pmatrix} 0\\1\\0 \end{pmatrix}, a_2=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\begin{pmatrix} 1\\0\\2 \end{pmatrix}, a_3=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\begin{pmatrix} -2\\0\\1 \end{pmatrix}$$

With this basis, I would get $\operatorname{diag}(6,6,1)$. How can I find the form mentioned above?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr  then one final

Comment: Anyway, given a symmetric matrix of all rational numbers, we can send it to a diagonal rational matrix $D.$ One final operation with a diagonal matrix takes one to diagonal all $\pm 1,0$

Comment: Scale each basis vector by dividing it by the square root of the magnitude of the corresponding eigenvalue.

Comment: So you're saying: $\left \{b_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\cdot \begin{pmatrix} 0\\1\\0 \end{pmatrix}, b_2=\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\begin{pmatrix} 1\\0\\2 \end{pmatrix},b_3=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\begin{pmatrix} -2\\0\\1 \end{pmatrix}\right \}=\left \{\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\begin{pmatrix} 0\\1\\0 \end{pmatrix},\frac{1}{\sqrt{30}}\begin{pmatrix} 1\\0\\2 \end{pmatrix},\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\begin{pmatrix} -2\\0\\1 \end{pmatrix} \right \}$